# Make a python 3 request using proxy

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, tor, socks

I want to make an anonymous web request using python 3.

I've tried few suggestions such as: [Make requests using Python over Tor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30286293/make-requests-using-python-over-tor)

I've managed to get a fake ip using this snippet:

**Installation**

> pip install requests requests[socks]

**Basic usage**

```
import requests

def get_tor_session():
    session = requests.session()
    # Tor uses the 9050 port as the default socks port
    session.proxies = {'http':  'socks5://127.0.0.1:9150',
                       'https': 'socks5://127.0.0.1:9150'}
    return session

# Make a request through the Tor connection
# IP visible through Tor
session = get_tor_session()
print(session.get("http://httpbin.org/ip").text)
# Above should print an IP different than your public IP

# Following prints your normal public IP
print(requests.get("http://httpbin.org/ip").text)
```

But that works only on port 9150 and when the tor web browser works.
I want to make a request without the tor browser, as i want to Dockerize the whole thing.

I've read about Socks5, and as you can see i've installed it, but when i make a request on port 9050 on the same snippet i get:

> requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
>   SOCKSHTTPConnectionPool(host='httpbin.org', port=80): Max retries
>   exceeded with url: /ip (Caused by
>   NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError
>   10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively
>   refused it',))

How can i solve it?

Thanks!

Comment: You want to use the Tor expert bundle as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38847434/get-requests-in-tor-network-without-installing-tor-browser-bundle/38856291#38856291

Answer (score 1, accepted):

10061 is 'connection refused'

That means there was nothing listening on that port you tried to connect to, no service is up and running (**no open port**) or **firewall** on target IP blocks it

you can test that port with telnet

```
telnet `IP` `PORT`
```

And also check this port issue on Windows: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45972637/getting-tor-controlport-to-work/46303954#46303954)

Comment: Solved!

The instructions in the link you gave didn't help. But I've figured that if i double click tor.exe it starts to listen..

Thanks!

Comment: No tor running means nothing on that port is listening (no open port)

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing this issue, in my case my tor service was not running, actually I was using `kalitorify` which is a transparent proxy, and whenever I was using this I was not be able to use normal sites such as google search or similar, so to use these sites I was turning off my kalitorify service which also turns off your tor service

So if you're also using that then also check it once